# Read from real time database not working Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display my username from my Realtime Database but I get this error in my console:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'studioName')
> at studiodash.js:24:71

I'm not really sure what the issue is. I made sure that my info matched up to what I have in my database. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem. I have provided a screenshot of my database setup and my code. Thanks!

FB Database:

[image]

JS:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize variables
const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.database();

//Check if user is signed in and their display info
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( function(user) {
  if (user) {
    database.ref('/studiopick/studio/users/' + user.uid).get().then(snapshot =>{
      document.getElementById
      ("studioName").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;
      ("profile-name").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;


    }).catch(e => {console.log(e)})
  } else {
    window.location.href ="login.html?error";
    alert("No active user please sign or sign up.");
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<!---Edit Profile--->
      <div class="edit-profile" id="edit-profile">
        <div class="card-body">
          <form id="studioForm">
            <h5 class="card-title text-muted"><strong>Edit Profile</strong></h5>
            <p class="profile-title" id="studioName"><b>Enter Studio Name</b></p>
            <p class="profile-location" id="profile-location">Bethesda, MD</p>
            <img class="star" src="Images/Star.png">
            <p class="profile-rating" id="profile-rating">4.25</p>
            <p class="profile-reviews" id="profile-reviews">8 reviews</p>
            
            <img class="card-img-bottom" id="profile-image" src="Images/placeholder.png">

            <button type="button" id="editprofilebutton" onclick="window.location.href='editprofile.html'">Edit Profile</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---Edit Profile--->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `val()` method of [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot#datasnapshotval) returns `null` if that node does not exists. In your case you are trying to read `ref('/studiopick/studio/users/' + user.uid)` where `user.uid` is Firebase Auth's UID and not some username (unless you are setting custom UID using Firebase Admin SDK).

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const snapshot = await database.ref('/studiopick/studio/users/' + user.uid).get()

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      document.getElementById("studioName").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;
    } else {
      console.log("User logged in but user's node not found in DB")
    }
  } else {
    window.location.href = "login.html?error";
    alert("No active user please sign or sign up.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Ohhh ok ok. How can I get my data to load based off the user that's logged in?

Comment: @lidxve first `console.log(user.uid)` and check what is your UID. It should be same in your database e.g. `/studiopick/studio/users/USER_UID` and not the name "lidxve". i.e. each user's UID must be used as DB key and not the name. Also you should check if the data exists as in my answer above to handle errors.

Comment: Ok. making changes now

Comment: it works now. thank you! Here's the code if anyone else needs it: // Initialize

//Check if user is signed in and their display info
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( function(user) {
  if (user) {
    database.ref('/studiopick/studio/users/' + user.uid).get().then(snapshot =>{
      document.getElementById("studioName").innerText = snapshot.val().studioName;}).catch(e => {console.log(e)})
  } else {
    window.location.href ="login.html?error";
    alert("No active user please sign or sign up.");
  }
});

Comment: one last thing, how can I display multiple values at once in my code?

Comment: @lidxve you'll have to set `.innerText` for each element individually just like studioName as you are using just HTML and JS. Web frameworks like [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) can make it a bit easier to render data.

Comment: Like this? I updated my code

Comment: @lidxve yes but complete statements e.g. `document.getElementById("profile-name").innerText = snapshot.val().firstName`